# Free classic psychological e-books for language learning

Tags: learning, resource, book

I want to master German via reading e-books. I was thinking about the classic works of psychology. At best I'd like to read the works of Sigmund Freud and Erich Fromm in original. I was searching the internet, but I've found the links to the articles about the authors, and not their books.

I think that the licences for these books should have already expired, at least when in comes to Freud, so they should be also available in e-book format (at best, PDF format).

Comment: Texts from Freud are 100 years old, texts from Fromm are 50 years old. But German is a living and evolving language. If you read Freud and From you will learn an oldish style of german language that noboby uses in real life today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a really tough guy - German is hard enough but to start with Freud.  Respect :-)

Why not to search in Gutenberg Project? Just for starter:
Das Unheimliche by Sigmund Freud - http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/34222

pozdrowionka

Comment: I'm not starting ;) I've probably skipped Gutenberg because search returned no results for Erich Fromm..

Comment: @Kris_R: Have you read something from Sigmund Freud? I have to admit that I'm German, but it is really easy to read,  clear and logical. I can only recommend reading it.

Comment: No, I haven't - not exactly my kind of literature.